# Creating font and text styles in android with Paint object

Tags: java, android

I am using the android Paint class to create text. I know how to set text size and color. I want to use Arial as font size and bold. How can I do it using the paint object. I have looked on the methods in the Paint class but couldn't find anything on how I can do it.

This is how I create my text style.

```
// Defining a paint object
paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(30);
paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Here is how I draw the text on a view.

```
g.drawString("My Text", 430, 774, paint);
```

How do I create the Arial font and bold text using the Paint class.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the **TextPaint** class instead of Paint. And can be implemented as below

```
TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
textPaint.setTextSize(30);
textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("Arial", Typeface.BOLD));
```

Answer (score 6):

Januari 2020

Copy the fonts you want to use to res/font 
(e.g. opensans_regular.ttf, opensans_italic.ttf, opensans_bolditalic.ttf, etc.) 
Watch out no '-' of capitals in the name!

Create New Font resource file opensans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/opensans_regular" />

    <font
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/opensans_italic" />

    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="700"
        app:font="@font/opensans_bold" />

    <font
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="700"
        app:font="@font/opensans_bolditalic" />

    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="200"
        app:font="@font/opensans_light" />

    <font
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="200"
        app:font="@font/opensans_lightitalic" />

    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="800"
        app:font="@font/opensans_extrabold" />

    <font
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="800"
        app:font="@font/opensans_extrabolditalic" />

</font-family>
```

In your MainActivity.java you can use the following code

```
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Typeface typeface;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
        // This does only works from SDK 28 and higher
        Typeface typefaceA = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.opensans);
        typeface = Typeface.create(typefaceA, 700, false);
    } else {
        // This always works (Whole name without .ttf)
        typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.opensans_bolditalic);
    }
    paint.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Bitmap getFontBitmap(String text, int color, float fontSizeSP, int typefaceStyle, boolean isCustomFont) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    if (isCustomFont) {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/bangla/bensen_handwriting.ttf"), typefaceStyle);
        paint.setTypeface(typeface);
    } else {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, typefaceStyle);
        paint.setTypeface(typeface);
    }
    int fontSizePX = ConvertDptoPx(mContext, fontSizeSP);
    int pad = (fontSizePX / 9);
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setTextSize(fontSizePX);

    int textWidth = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + pad * 2);
    int height = (int) (fontSizePX / 0.75);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(textWidth, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    float xOriginal = pad;
    canvas.drawText(text, xOriginal, fontSizePX, paint);
    return bitmap;
}

private int ConvertDptoPx(Context context, float dip) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dip, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

And then call

```
Bitmap bitmap = getFontBitmap("Ahamadullah", color, 22, Typeface.BOLD, true);
```

or

```
Bitmap bitmap = getFontBitmap("Ahamadullah", color, 22, Typeface.NORMAL | Typeface.ITALIC, false);
```